# Modifying a monospace font (fontforge)

Tags: fonts, font-design, font-forge

I am attempting to swap out the numerals in an existing monospace font (ttf) with some from a different monospace font (also ttf).

I can't seem to get fontforge to export a mono ttf though. Even just opening the font I want to modify and immediately exporting it results in a non-mono flagged font that can't be loaded into gVim. Is there another tool that can be used for this?

Comment: Does this help? https://fontforge.github.io/faq.html#monospace

Comment: Since I'm starting with an already working monospace font, the answer in the FAQ isn't helpful. Fontforge is either failing to flag it as mono or actually breaking something in the font when it is being loaded/saved to ttf.

Comment: Yes, but are all the glyphs exactly the same size, as they must be according to the help page?

Comment: I set all the glyphs to the same width and was able to export a monospaced font. I'm not convinced that this isn't an issue with Fontforge though, as I tried with several different monospaced fonts and had to manually fix the widths in order to export correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I posted the link, because that is what it implies you would need to do. So, there is nothing wrong with fontforge, it's working exactly as it should according to the documentation.

Comment: No I believe that Fontforge is causing the problem, as opening the font with a different editor resulted in all glyphs being the same width and successfully outputting to monospaced. Aforementioned editor caused other problems though.

Comment: So Fontforge is taking monospaced fonts and causing them to actually not be monospaced upon loading from ttf. So yes the link is correct, but doesn't help with fontforge actually breaking mono fonts that are being loaded in.

Comment: @BillyKerr your link does not work (404); did you mean this? https://fontforge.org/docs/faq.html#faq-monospace

Comment: @mirabilos - do you realize that link was posted over a year ago?

Comment: @BillyKerr which is *precisely* the reason I posted an updated link, so that people visiting here later can check that. (Please confirm it is this one.)

Comment: @mirabilos - I can confirm nothing. Both the link and content may have changed since posting. However, it does mention how to create a monospace font.